# how to combing variable name with string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have object like this

```
var obj = {
   option1 : {
     title : "string", 
     options : {}
   },
   option2 : {
     title : "string", 
     options : {}
   },
   option3 : {
     title : "string", 
     options : {}
   },
   option4 : {
     title : "string", 
     options : {}
   }
}
```

I'm trying to get the title based on index of html node

```
$("#id div").each(function(){
   $(this).html(obj.["option" + ($(this).index() + 1)].title);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).html(obj.["option" + ($(this).index() + 1)].title);
//              ^ Get rid of this
```

So you want this:

```
$(this).html(obj["option" + ($(this).index() + 1)].title);
```

The square bracket syntax is an *alternative* to the dot syntax. You use one or the other, not both. The grammer for [call expressions](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2) in the spec shows this clearly:

> *CallExpression* :
>       *MemberExpression Arguments*
>       *CallExpression Arguments*
>       *CallExpression* `[` *Expression* `]`
>       *CallExpression* `.` *IdentifierName*

Comment: seems to me when some of you guys found the answer easy vote down, no problem, I've searched in SO but didnt find anything thanks again

Comment: @CameronA - I didn't vote down but I think the reason for the downvotes on this question is that you could have worked it out easily yourself. You will have an error in the console, something like "Unexpected token [" which would have given you a big clue as to where the problem was occurring. But anyway, you're welcome, I'm glad I could help :)